# Convert from curl to java code

Tags: java, curl

I have to convert this to Java

```
curl -X GET \
 -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: AppId" \
 -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ApPKeY" \
 -G \
 --data-urlencode 'where={
 "playerName": {
 "$nin": [
   "Jonathan Walsh",
   "Dario Wunsch",
   "Shawn Simon"
 ]
}
}' \
--data-urlencode 'order=score,-name' \
--data-urlencode 'limit=200' \
--data-urlencode 'skip=400' \
--data-urlencode 'keys=score,playerName' \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

For all the `-H`, I have wrote :- `httpConn.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Application-Id", "AppId");`. But I cannot figure out what to do for the `-G` and the `-- data-urlencode`.

Comment: You should explain what these options do. That way you can also get answers from java developers who are not familiar with curl and don't feel like looking up the documentation.

Comment: Also, am I right to assume that your `httpConn` object is of class [`HttpURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)?

Comment: @Philipp yes. It is an object of `HttpURLConnection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-G` option specifies that the HTTP GET method is to be used. You can set that with [setRequestMethod](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod-java.lang.String-), but the default is already GET, so you don't need to do this.

The `-- data-urlencode` option specifies either POST or GET data to be passed along with the request. In case of the GET method, that data is appended to the URL in form of key value pairs in the form `key=value` separated by `&`. That means you just need to append those strings to your URL separated by `&`... or you can use the method [setRequestProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Thanks Philipp. I don't know why `setRequestProperty` did not work with `setRequestMethod("GET")`. But it worked when I put the GET parameters directly in the url